# Why is this not valid YAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I can't figure out why this code trips up the rails YAML parser.

```
sections:
  [
    {title: "Journal Entry Testing",
     procedures:
       ["Select a sample of journal entries prepared during the year and determine if they were prepared correctly and approved.”]
    }    
  ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the non-matching double-quotes, enlarged to highlight the difference:

## ["Select a sample ... and approved.”]

See how the ending quotes are "smart" quotes?

With that fixed, it passes at http://yamllint.com/, and gets turned into actual YAML.